# question about basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis and dimension of the subspace $V\subset\mathbb R^n$ defined by the equation
$x_1 +x_2 +···+x_n = 0$ for all $x \in V$.

thx a lot. I am completely lost and confused about how to find a basis.

Comment: Start e.g. with $(1,0,0,\dots,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,0,\dots,0,-1)$. And expand on a natural way.

Answer (score 0):

Inductively.  For $n=1$ you have ${\rm dim}(V_n)=0$ and a base given by $\emptyset$.  For $n=k+1$, any element $x$ in $V_n$ can be expressed uniquely as $\lambda(e_n-e_1)+y$ such that $y\in V_k$ ($\lambda=x_n$ in this case), so you can see that $e_2-e_1,\ldots,e_n-e_1$ form a $n-1$ element base for $V_n$.